# Windows clang Hello World lnk4217

Tags: c++, clang

I have installed clang version 6.0 as well as Visual Studio 2017. I am compiling a simple 'hello world' application:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

using

```
clang hello.cpp
```

This gives me warnings:

```
hello-d1b2c6.o : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __std_terminate 
imported in function "int `public: static unsigned __int64 __cdecl
std::char_traits<char>::length(char const * const)'::`1'::dtor$2"
(?dtor$2@?0??length@?$char_traits@D@std@@SA_KQEBD@Z@4HA)

hello-d1b2c6.o : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _CxxThrowException 
imported in function "public: void __cdecl std::ios_base::clear(int,bool)"
(?clear@ios_base@std@@QEAAXH_N@Z)
```

I am aware that I can mitigate these warnings by using `clang-cl` (as suggested [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42545078/5909613) and [here](https://github.com/fstudio/clangbuilder/issues/25)), however, I do not want to do that without fully understanding the implications.

So here are my actual questions:

1. What do these warnings mean or what is causing them?
2. What does using `clang-cl` change and what do I have to keep in mind when using it? (I guess there is a reason to not use it all the time)
3. Are there other ways to not receive these warnings (except for turning off warnings)?

Comment: You should compile with clang++.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Why? And this does not affect the warnings.

Comment: From the user manual: `clang-cl is an alternative command-line interface to Clang, designed for compatibility with the Visual C++ compiler, cl.exe.` [link](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#clang-cl)

Comment: Because it makes sure you invoke the C++ frontend, not the C one. And that is unsurprising, I did not post this as an answer on purpose.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thanks for educating me (this is no sarcasm btw). And for anyone wanting to know more about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20052006/5909613

Comment: @Borgleader I have read that, but I don't know how exactly this is achieved and why this is not always enabled. I assume there are drawbacks/implications for this.

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979491/how-to-delete-warnings-lnk4217-and-lnk4049 somehow relevant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this issue myself and did some investigation.

#### What do these warnings mean?

There is a detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6979586/2659307) (that I do not fully understand), but the high level idea, as I understand it, is there is a mismatch between the object file (`.o` file) that `clang` compiled and the library file (`.lib` file) that is being linked with.

Therefore, although the program seems to work, it's probably a bad idea to just ignore the warnings.

#### What is causing them?

The warning is being issued by the Microsoft linker, `link.exe`, which `clang` invokes.  Clang does not include its own linker.  By default, on Windows, it looks for the Microsoft Visual Studio C compiler headers, libraries, and linker.  You can see exactly what it is doing by adding the `-v` (verbose) switch to the `clang` command line.

I'm not sure how Clang finds these tools.  I'd forgotten I even had them installed, and they certainly are not on the `PATH`.  I think Clang must have dug them out of the registry somehow.

#### What does using clang-cl change?

It changes the switches passed to the Clang compiler (also called `clang` or `clang++` or `clang-cl`, but with the `-cc1` switch passed) and the linker (MSVC `link.exe`).  At a high level, `clang-cl` tries to emulate the MSVC `cl.exe` compiler, while `clang` ... does something else.  I'm not sure what.  It's not emulating MinGW; see below.

The detailed differences can be seen in the respective `-v` outputs.   Using `clang++` and `clang-cl` from LLVM 8.0.1, I see these compiler switch differences:

```
clang-cl has but clang++ lacks:
  -relaxed-aliasing
  -mllvm
  -x86-asm-syntax=intel
  -D_MT
  -flto-visibility-public-std
  --dependent-lib=libcmt
  --dependent-lib=oldnames
  -stack-protector 2
  -fms-volatile
  -fdiagnostics-format msvc

clang++ has but clang-cl lacks:
  -fcxx-exceptions
  -fexceptions
```

And during linking, `clang++` passes `-defaultlib:libcmt`, while `clang-cl` does not.

The big difference I see is `clang-cl` passes `-D_MT`, enabling the thread-aware C and C++ standard libraries.  I think it's a bad idea to mix modules compiled with and without `_MT`.  The mismatch regarding `-fcxx-exceptions` is also concerning, suggesting that C++ exceptions might not work.

`clang-cl` also passes `-flto-visibility-public-std`, the flag recommended by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42752769/2659307) to a related question.  I don't know whether this flag is merely suppressing a warning or significantly changing the way the code is compiled.

#### What do I have to keep in mind when using it?

As I understand it, you want to use `clang-cl` if and only if you want Clang to do its best to emulate the Microsoft `cl.exe` compiler, including using its header files and invoking the Microsoft linker with its libraries.

Furthermore, I'm unaware of a reason to use `clang++` on Windows without also specifying `-target` (next section).  Without `-target`, `clang++` still uses the MSVC headers, libraries, and linker, but does not pass the switches needed to emulate the `cl.exe` compiler.  I suspect this will always result in an executable with mismatched object code.

#### Are there other ways to not receive these warnings?

In my case, I want Clang to emulate the [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) `gcc` compiler and invoke its linker instead.  To do that, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47148323/2659307), add `-target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` to the `clang++` command line:

```
  $ clang++.exe -target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu -o cpphello.exe cpphello.cpp
```

That command produces no warnings, and a working executable.

By adding `-v` to that command line, you can see the details, including invocation of the MinGW `ld.exe` linker.

Note: You need a MinGW `gcc` on your `PATH`!

#### What about clang versus clang++?

Like `gcc`, `clang` *will* compile C++ code if the file uses an extension it recognizes, such as `.cc` or `.cpp`.  However, it does not pass the C++ standard library to the linker, even when you compile and link in a single command.  Therefore, it's generally best to use `clang++` exclusively when working with C++ code.

Likewise, `clang -x c++` can be used to compile C++, but again does not pass the C++ standard library to the linker.